# Sending the packets through web service in perl, in response getting the error of ssl

Tags: perl, web-services, ssl

I am using webservice to send the packets through my Perl program,

in response I am getting the following error:

```
<html>
<head><title>An Error Occurred</title></head>
<body>
<h1>An Error Occurred</h1>
<p>500 SSL negotiation failed: </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that I need to install one module for the ssl, my question is if I need to install the module then which module? and if there is any alternative then pl?

Comment: What module you are using in your current program to send the packets or you are using your own code?

Comment: right now i am using $ENV{HTTPS_VERSION} = 3;

Comment: i am using my perl program to send the packets

Comment: I propose to close the question because it is too unspecific and does not contain any information needed to reproduce or understand the problem. Obviously there is something wrong with the SSL handshake, but there are no details about the target URL nor about the program used, which libraries are used and which versions of these libraries - i.e. nothing which would make it possible to get to the root of the problem.